Setting view's header text in navigation bar
I have a sheet on which I wish to show the title of the view in a specific way. The title should be leading and should not be horizontally alignment with tool bar trailing item, but should be below it. Please refer the attached screenshots since it's easier to explain it that way.
Code:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .onAppear {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
            SheetA()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetA: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.1).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Text("This is sheet A. Navigation title should be below 'Done' button")
                }
            }
            .toolbarBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.1), for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("").font(.body.bold()).foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            Text("Hello World. How are you?").font(.largeTitle.bold())
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 40.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Done").font(.body.bold()).foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented) /// disable dismiss with a drag/slide-down.

        }
    }
}

What I want:

What I am getting with my code:

I want "Hello World - How are you?" line right above the navigation bar line and the text should cover the space below 'Done' button as well, just like it does in the first screenshot.
How do I achieve this?
Edit: Adding some more details to avoid the confusion. This title text is dynamic, so it could be longer. If it's long, then I would like to either word wrap it onto next line or wrap it into a horizontal scroll view so user can scroll it to view entire text. In my code, I am already wrapping "Text("Hello World. How are you?")" inside a horizontal scroll view.

Why are you making it a toolbar item? How about just using a VStack { Text(...) Spacer() }?

You should just be setting .navigationTitle("Hello World. How are you?") since you've already set .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)

@Sweeper - It's a dynamic title, so I may want to word wrap it or put it into a horizontal scroll view if the title is extremely long. Hence I was thinking of fixing this via ToolbarItem.

Thanks @pilchard! Setting title using good old navigation title worked, but it won't allow me to customize the style i.e. word wrap of show title into horizontal scroll. Hence I think I will have to find the solution around using ToolbarItem.

So? How would using a VStack prevent you from using a ScrollView?

VStack isn't preventing me from using horizontal scroll view.
If you check my code, "Text("Hello World. How are you?")" is wrapped inside a scrollview which works fine. Only problem is the placement of the title. It's not right above the navigation bar line and also leaves the space for 'Done' button towards the end, even though 'Done' button is above the text.

See also Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI if you want to style the title your own way

I solved it without adding "Hello World..." as navigation bar title but instead adding it as a view. Added my answer below, but if you still could think of a better solution then plz share. Thanks!

I was able to solve it without setting the title as navigation bar title, but instead adding it to view's body. Still working on the divider, but this is very close to what I am looking for.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .onAppear {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
            SheetA()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetA: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        Text("Hello World - How are you? This is long text.").font(.largeTitle.bold())
                    }
                    
                    Divider().frame(height: 5.0)
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10.0)
                .padding(.top, -10.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 70.0)
   
                VStack {
                    Text("This is sheet A. Navigation title should be below 'Done' button")
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("" ,displayMode: .large)
            .toolbarBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.1), for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Done").font(.body.bold()).foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)
        }
    }
}

